# Having trouble getting Blazor to rerender component on change in state shared between components

Tags: c#, state, blazor

#### Context

I'm following a pattern that's something like https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/ or https://jonhilton.net/blazor-state-management/

So I have two razor components `Hen.razor` and `Basket.razor` as child components inside `index.razor`. A button inside `Hen` adds to the number of eggs displayed inside `Basket`.

The button calls a service I've injected called `EggService` that handles the number of eggs in `Basket` by storing it in local storage using Blazored.LocalStorage.

#### Problem

Clicking the button increases the number of eggs in local storage **but** doesn't update the `Basket` component unless I refresh.

#### Code

Repository for convenience: https://github.com/EducatedStrikeCart/EggTest/

EggService:

```
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

namespace BlazorSandbox.Services
{
    public class EggService
    {
        public event Action OnChange;

        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

        public EggService(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
        {
            this._localStorageService = localStorageService;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetEggs()
        {
            int currentEggs =  await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<int>("Eggs");
            return currentEggs;
        }

        public async Task AddEgg()
        {
            int newEggs = await GetEggs();
            if (newEggs == null)
            {
                newEggs = 0;
            } else
            {
                newEggs += 1;
            }
            await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync("Eggs", newEggs);
            OnChange?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Hen:

```
@using BlazorSandbox.Services
@inject EggService EggService

<div>
    <h3>Hen</h3>
<button @onclick="TakeAnEgg">Take an egg</button>
</div>


@code {
    public async Task TakeAnEgg()
    {
        await EggService.AddEgg();
    }
}
```

Egg:

```
@using BlazorSandbox.Services
@inject EggService EggService
@implements IDisposable

<div>
    <h3>Basket</h3>
    Eggs: @Eggs
</div>


@code {
    public int Eggs { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Eggs = await EggService.GetEggs();
        EggService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        EggService.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Index:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorSandbox.Services
@inject EggService EggService

<h1>
    Eggs!
</h1>
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
    <Hen />
    <Basket />
</div>
@code {

}
```

Program.cs:

```
using BlazorSandbox;
using BlazorSandbox.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<EggService>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

---

#### Solution

Special thank you to person who deleted their comment. I'm kind of new to asking questions on StackOverflow so I'm sorry if I should've selected your answer as the Answer!

```
@code {
    public int Eggs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        //Subscribe
        EggService.OnChange += UpdateEgg;
        //Set value of Eggs on load
        UpdateEgg();
    }

    public void UpdateEgg()
    {
        // Set value of Eggs to new value and trigger component rerender
        InvokeAsync(async () => {Eggs = await EggService.GetEggs(); StateHasChanged(); });

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Unsubscribe
        EggService.OnChange -= UpdateEgg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few oddities in your code.

```
if (newEggs == null)
```

This is an `int`, so it can never be null. The default value for `int` is `0`. You should be seeing a warning for this.

```
Eggs = await EggService.GetEggs();
```

After you set `Eggs` here, you never update it anywhere in your code! So even if you call `StateHasChanged`, there is nothing to update.

What you will want to do is keep track of the egg count inside of your `EggService` and then inside of your `Basket` component you will need a way to know that the egg count has increased so you can update your `Egg` property and then call `StateHasChanged`. Let me know if you need help with this.

Comment: This is actually a stripped down example I made to help myself understand this problem for a larger project so I may have left in some unnecessary code like the checking for that null int 


My understanding is that subscribing to changes through `EggService.OnChange += StateHasChanged;` in `Basket` would force the `Basket` to be rerendered when `OnChange?.Invoke();` is called inside `EggService.AddEgg()`  when the button gets clicked in `Hen`.

Comment: What happens when you call `StateHasChanged` is a `RenderFragment` (which is a `delegate` that holds a function to execute the render tree builder) is passed to the render engine to execute. When this is executed, the render engine compares the previous render tree with the new one and **only** updates the differences. This means if there are no differences, nothing changes! In other words, calling `StateHasChanged` will have no effect if there are no changes from the previous render tree.

Comment: So after reading up on [Blazor RenderTree/ component lifecyle](https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/) my understanding now is that `OnInitializedAsync` is only called once and is not called again by `StateHasChanged` . Because of this, there is no difference seen by the render engine and thus there are no changes. Is that correct? Is there a good way around this without having to move the logic inside `EggService` into `Basket`?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. The straightforward way to do this is to create a method in your `Basket` component that subscribes to the `OnChange` event in your `EggService`. In this method you would update the `Egg` property and call `StateHasChanged`. Let me know if you need me to show the code.